# Using Elasticsearch Terraform EC provider to deploy a cluster in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, terraform

I am looking to deploy ECE (Elastic Cloud Enterprise) in AWS with Terraform. Reading through the documentation, I'm still not clear how this model works.

In the provider below, what is the reason for the endpoint? Is terraform connecting to this endpoint with the specified username and password? And are these credentials are being provided with the ECE license?

Hence, I'm thinking that the ECE installation endpoint can't be private. But I need to provision this privately - probably won't be able to do it via Terraform. Any experience with this?

```
provider "ec" {
  # ECE installation endpoint
  endpoint = "https://my.ece-environment.corp"

  # If the ECE installation has a self-signed certificate
  # you must set insecure to true.
  insecure = true

  username = "my-username"
  password = "my-password"
}
```

```
data "ec_stack" "latest" {
  version_regex = "latest"
  region        = "us-east-1"
}

resource "ec_deployment" "example_minimal" {
  # Optional name.
  name = "my_example_deployment"

  # Mandatory fields
  region                 = "us-east-1"
  version                = data.ec_stack.latest.version
  deployment_template_id = "aws-io-optimized-v2"

  elasticsearch {}
}
```